# How to take users from a table that are not in another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to take users who are not in another collection (UserRates)

My code:

```
const rateUsers = await UserRates.find({  }).populate('user');
const users = await User.find({ status: "active" }, { user: { $nin: { rateUsers } } })
```

is don`t work

Most likely I'm doing it all wrong. Can you suggest how this can be done? There is a user (ObjectID) field in the UserRates collection and I need to take those who are not in UserRares in the User collection

Answer (score 0):

and i try it:

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "user_rates",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "user",
          "as": "rates"
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "rates.user": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

it work!